# GLSurfaceView in a PopupWindow

Tags: android, popupwindow, glsurfaceview

I need to add a `GLSurfaceView` to a `FrameLayout` in a `PopupWindow`. The problem is that, internally, the `SurfaceView` requests the token from the current window. `PopupWindows` don't have their own tokens, so I give it the token from the popup parent instead, like so:

```
class MySurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
   ...
  @Override
  public IBinder getWindowToken() {
      // I set the mPopupParent manually to be the parent of the PopupWindow in question
      return mPopupParent.getWindowToken();
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Now, even though `MySurfaceView` is added to a `FrameLayout` that is the content of the `PopupWindow`, it doesn't draw there. It draws on the view that I got the token from.

How can I get it to draw on the layout it is actually added to?

EDIT:
Just to give some more detail, in case it makes a difference, the mPopupParent is an IME view (a keyboard, essentially).

Comment: You have to stay stick to the `PopupWindow`? I think you should use a plain `Activity` with the `Dialog` theme instead.

Comment: I'm working on an IME, there is no Activity to work with, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried adding the SurfaceView directly to the `WindowManager` via `addView`?

Comment: Yes, it fills the whole screen. It is a solution, but not a particularly good one. So far, I was able to just move that token owning window in line with my popup window and make it invisible, so it APPEARS that the SurfaceView is above the popup, but that's obviously not very robust.

Comment: Have you considered using a TextureView instead? It doesn't suffer from SurfaceView's limitations.

Comment: So close - that looks like a good candidate, but only available from API v14 (I need to support v8). I don't see it in the support library either...

Answer (score 0):

```
I got something just like yours,and finally these ways work out:
```

A .  Use a Dialog

B.   Use the android.view.WindowManager